# XMLHttpRequest Level 2 events: equivlents to readyState

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, readystate, xmlhttprequest-level2

XMLHttpRequest Level 2 adds a number of more meaningful events over the `onreadystatechange` one.

Is there a correspondence between some of these events and the `readyState` values?

As far as I can tell:

```
1   loadstart
2   progress
3   ?
4   loadend; load
```

I haven’t worked out equivalent for 3, which is a bit vague anyway.

Comment: according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) progress is readystate 3

Comment: Did you look at the spec? https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-responsetype-attribute The joke is, it has nothing... :) which points you to https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I observe using the following code:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", ev);
oReq.addEventListener("load", ev);
oReq.addEventListener("loadstart", ev);
oReq.addEventListener("loadend", ev);
oReq.addEventListener("readystatechange", ev);


oReq.open('GET', '/blah');

function ev(e) {
    console.log(e.type, oReq.readyState);
}
oReq.send();
```

Output result

```
readystatechange 1
loadstart 1
readystatechange 2
readystatechange 3
progress 3
readystatechange 4
load 4
loadend 4
```

so it seems it is

1. loadstart
2. ??? - no equivalent - (which is headers received)
3. progress
4. load/loadend

Comment: It appears that `progress` may be browser dependent. Safari reports it as state 2, while Chrome & Firefox report it as 3.

Comment: Safari is becoming the new Internet Explorer :p